# Possible database problems!

Tags: support

The following question was attributed to me, but it is not mine (it is not my writing style, nor was I using this web site back in November 2010; in fact, I only started using this web site within the past two months):

Link:  [Is "can not" unambiguous?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4620/is-can-not-unambiguous)

[image]

Although I don't mind getting bonus points (which is what has effectively happened here), they really do belong to the person who actually wrote the question.

I do hope the database that this web site relies on is okay.

Comment: What OS you use?

Comment: On this computer I'm using 64-bit Windows 7 Operating System with Service Pack 1 installed.  I'd be surprised if the OS played a significant role here though.

Comment: This is extraordinary. And you're sure this wasn't an old non-registered account you used a few times back then? Oh, and your number of open tabs reminds me of my browser! Bad habit...

Comment: @Cerberus:  No, and I definitely wouldn't have used the name "Pascal Cuoq" (as @Michael Mrozek noted in his helpful answer; I don't recognize that name) if I did because I don't use pseudonyms for serious communities like this one (even in MMORPGs I tend to use "Sir Randolf" which isn't much of a stretch from my real name).  _By the way, Opera is awesome for bringing back tabs, and I have lots of stacked tabs too so there's a lot more there than meets the eye -- I don't see it as a bad habit, rather I find it to be a wonderful productivity tool.  =)_

Comment: Holy crap those tabs!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case there was a bit of account confusion because there were overlapping "fake" emails in your user information, and a moderator (me in this case) mistakenly elected to merge the accounts.

I went ahead and disassociated this question from your account, and I'll patch up the other user later.

In the future, I recommend picking a more *unique* fake email address.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I appreciate you fixing that.  The reason I used an _RFC-sanctioned_ fake eMail address was that I get way too many eMail messages, and having to set up with OpenID.org (or the others) would require that my eMail address be made available to a number of different services.  I may change this in the near future to a real eMail address, but I prefer to understand more about how these systems share information with third parties first.

Answer (score 4):

In the [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cache:https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4620/is-can-not-unambiguous) version the owner is [Pascal Cuoq](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/1095/pascal-cuoq), a deleted user:

[image: Screenshot of the cached version]

Was that account possibly merged into yours?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Hmm, this is very interesting because for you it's showing someone else's name instead of your own.  It still shows my name when I browse to it (after reading your answer).  The number of votes shows 4 for you too, which is also different from my display that shows 5 votes.

Comment: @Randolf That was the cached version, an old copy of the page. I see you as the owner when I look at the real version

Comment: The gravatars *are* identical looking, so it may've triggered one of those mergers.

Comment: @Once Good point. It wouldn't happen automatically, but a mod probably noticed they have the same e-mail (amongst other details) and merged them

Comment: @Once Great:  If so, then that's a very serious design flaw that could potentially have security implications for moderator accounts.

Comment: @Michael Mrozek:  This system doesn't let people sign up with their eMail address (which I also find unusual from a design perspective).  Does the number of votes show 5 now that you've cleared your cache?

Comment: @Randolf Email is what determines your gravatar. Yes, the same image can be keyed to multiple emails, but I'm pretty sure that all of the moderators who do merges will do it based on the actual email, not just the image.

Comment: @Randolf You're required to specify your e-mail when you ask a question anonymously; if you're registered you can set it on your profile page

Comment: @Michael Mrozek:  I had trouble getting signed up initially because OpenID.org ignore eMail requests for help when their system fails, but I eventually did get signed up with the beta OpenID alternative provided by StackExchange.  I find that the OpneID thing is still very touchy and sometimes it forgets who I am.  Basically I'm just avoiding all the OpenID stuff for a while until things are working properly, and then I might try again.